# What numeric dictionary collection re-sorts items when a duplicate number is added?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, collections

My C# program allows users to rank projects numerically by priority.  I've written a routine which automatically resorts the projects by rank when a user modifies a project's rank. So when the project ranked priority 3 is changed to 1 the routine resorts the top 3 projects. Those previously ranked 1, 2 become ranked 2, 3. Similarly when the priority 1 project becomes priority 3 then those ranked 2, 3 become 1, 2.

Does an existing collection class have this feature built in? If so a code sample would also be appreciated.

Comment: what about SortedList class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @milenpavlov Though a sortedlist doesnt change the prior ranked to a lesser rank?

Comment: I think you are going to need to loop and change the values.

Answer (score 5):

C# has a `SortedSet<T>` collection which can be sorted with a custom `IComparer<T>` provided by the user.

However, the set will *not* react to changes in items that are already in your set, i.e. if you change the priority of an item when it is already in the set, it would not be moved up or down automatically.

You need to remove the item from the `SortedSet<T>`, change its priority, and then add it back. This way the collection will put it at its new place, moving other items to accommodate the change in order:

```
SortedSet<Project> prioritizedProjects = new SortedSet<Project>(new CompareProjByPriority());
...
Project rePrioritize = ...;
prioritizedProjects.Remove(rePrioritize);
rePrioritize.Priority = 1;
prioritizedProjects.Add(rePrioritize);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in collection that "understands" the concept of ranks. However if rank is an imaginary concept of continuous numbers, a simple `List<Project>` would do:

```
List<Project> projects = GetProjects();
Project project = projects[2]; // grab project on rank 3 (index 2 since it's 0 based)
projects.RemoveAt(2);          // pick it up
projects.Insert(0, project);   // place the project in front of the first
```

This would then allow users to "prioritize" projects.

However if rank is a property of `Project`, you would need to manually update each affected element; this should not be the responsibility of a built-in collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend some collection, ex : generic list to do this

```
public static bool SetValue<T>(this List<T> collection, int oldValue, int newValue)
{
    if ((Math.Min(newValue, oldValue) <= -1) ||
        (Math.Max(newValue, oldValue) > collection.Count()))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (newValue != oldValue)
    {
        var value = collection[oldValue];
        collection.RemoveAt(oldValue);
        if (newValue == collection.Count())
        {
            collection.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            collection.Insert(newValue, value);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

After that you could do:

```
        var items = new List<char> { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
        var start = string.Join(", ", items); //"A, B, C"
        items.SetValue(2, 0);
        var result = string.Join(", ", items); //"C, A, B"
```

It is 2, 0 and not 3, 1 because first element is 0 not 1.

Comment: To do this properly is a bit bulky, but could be useful for many cases, so i create a extension function. I check that boundary conditions are valid and after that, because you can't insert new last element - i use Add.